# how to split the text using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
f_output.write('\n{}, {}\n'.format(filename, summary))
```

I am printing the output as the name of the file. I am getting the output as VCALogParser_output_ARW.log, VCALogParser_output_CZC.log and so on. but I am interested only in printing ARW, CZC and so on. So please someone can tell me how to split this text ?

Comment: You can use a regular expression.

Comment: Is it without `.log` as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in `CZC` and `ARW` without the `.log` then, you can do it with [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.search) method:

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = 'VCALogParser_output_ARW.log'
>>> s2 = 'VCALogParser_output_CZC.log'
>>> re.search(r'.*_(.*)\.log', s1).group(1)
'ARW'
>>> re.search(r'.*_(.*)\.log', s2).group(1)
'CZC'
```

Or better maker your patten `p` then call its `search` method when formatting your string:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'.*_(.*)\.log')
>>> 
>>> '\n{}, {}\n'.format(p.search(s1).group(1), p.search(s2).group(1))
'\nARW, CZC\n'
```

Also, it might be helpful using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub) with positive look ahead and group naming:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'.*(?<=_)(?P<mystr>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.log$')
>>> 
>>> 
>>> p.sub('\g<mystr>', s1)
'ARW'
>>> p.sub('\g<mystr>', s2)
'CZC'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> '\n{}, {}\n'.format(p.sub('\g<mystr>', s1), p.sub('\g<mystr>', s2))
'\nARW, CZC\n'
```

In case, you are not able or you don't want to use `re` module, then you can define lengths of strings that you don't need and index your string variables with them:

```
>>> i1 = len('VCALogParser_output_')
>>> i2 = len ('.log')
>>> 
>>> '\n{}, {}\n'.format(s1[i1:-i2], s2[i1:-i2])
'\nARW, CZC\n'
```

But keep in mind that the above is valid as long as you have those common strings in all of your string variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

this will give you : 'ARW'

```
summary.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

and this will give you: 'CZC'

Answer (score 0):

```
fname.split('_')[-1]
```

is rought but this will give you 'CZC.log', 'ARW.log' and so on, assuming that all files have the same underscore-delimited format.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the file is always such that it ends with `_ARW.log` or `_CZC.log` this is really easy to do just using the standard string `split()` method, with two consecutive splits:

```
shortname = filename.split("_")[-1].split('.')[0]
```

Or, to make it (arguably) a bit more readable, we can use the `os` module:

```
shortname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0].split("_")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
>>> s1 = 'VCALogParser_output_ARW.log'
>>> s2 = 'VCALogParser_output_CZC.log'
>>> s1.split('_')[2].split('.')[0]
ARW
>>> s2.split('_')[2].split('.')[0]
CZC
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse file name correctly, so basically my guess is that you wanna to strip file extension `.log` and prefix `VCALogParser_output_` to do that it's enough to use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) rather than using **str.split**
2. Use [**os.linesep**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep) when you writing to file to have cross-browser

Code below would perform desired result(after applying steps listed above):

```
    import os

    filename = 'VCALogParser_output_SOME_NAME.log'
    summary = 'some summary'
    fname = filename.replace('VCALogParser_output_', '').replace('.log', '')
    linesep = os.linesep

    f_output.write('{linesep}{fname}, {summary}{linesep}'
                   .format(fname=fname, summary=summary, linesep=linesep))

    # or if vars in execution scope strictly controlled pass locals() into format
    f_output.write('{linesep}{fname}, {summary}{linesep}'.format(**locals()))
```